# An application of the coarea formula

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, geometric-measure-theory

I'm trying understand the proof of the lemma $1.1$ of [this](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1090349447) paper (see page $366$), but I didn't understand how coarea formula was applied to obtain the following equality:

> $$\int_K |\nabla v| + v |\nabla u| = \int_a^b |\partial^* F_t \cap K| - \int_K \int_a^b \chi_{\{ v(x) < t \}} |\nabla u| + b \int_K |\nabla u|$$

I would like to understand how the equality above is related to the coarea formula. The coarea formula used is presented [here](https://maths-proceedings.anu.edu.au/CMAProcVol3/CMAProcVol3-Complete.pdf) on page $70$ (it's the page $82$ of the PDF).